# (C++) serialize object of class from external library

Tags: c++, serialization

Is there any way to serialize (or, more generally to save to file) an object from a class that I can't modify?

All of the serialization approaches that I've found so far require some manner of intrusion, at the very least adding methods to the class, adding friends etc.

If the object is from a class in a library that I didn't write myself, I don't want to have to change the classes in that library.

More concretely: I'm developing a module-based application which also involves inter-module communication (which is as simple as: one module, the source, is the owner of some data, and another module, the destination, has a pointer to that data, and there's a simple updating/hand shaking protocol between the modules). I need to be able to save the state of the modules (which data was last communicated between the modules). Now, it would be ideal if this communication could handle any type, including ones from external libraries. So I need to save this data when saving the module state.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no native serialization in C++, at least according to the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) on the topic of serialization.

There's a good FAQ resource on this topic [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization#serialize-overview) that might be useful if you haven't found it already.  This is just general info on serialization, though; it doesn't address the specific problem you raise.

There are a couple of (very) ugly approaches I can think of.  You've likely already thought of and rejected these, but I'm throwing them out there just in case:

1. Do you have access to all the data members of the class?  Worst case, you could read those out into a c-style structure, apply your compiler's version of "packed" to keep the sizes of things predictable, and get a transferable binary blob that way.
2. You could cast a pointer to the object as a pointer to uint8_t, and treat the whole thing like an array.  This will get messy if there are references, pointers, or a vtable in there.  This approach might work for POD objects, though.

Comment: I've read that FAQ. I don't have access to all data members, not right away. A class from an external library would only expose an interface, all data members would be private. Also, casting to a pointer wouldn't work since many of the objects would have pointer members. Libraries such as Boost::Serialization have a mechanism for tracking objects from pointer members, but it also requires modifying the object's class.